# Replace words from an array of objects (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I want to replace multiple words of an string/multiline. Keywords and Replacewords are taken by an array of objects. 
It works perfectly for the first object in the array, but not for the other objects in the array.

```js
var aString = 'I have many animals, for Example a Dog, a little Mice, a Kangaroo I´ve got as well, and I even have got a Cat.';

var Array = new Array();
array[0].firstanimal = 'Dog';
array[0].secondanimal = 'Cat';
array[1].firstanimal = 'Mice';
array[1].secondanimal = 'Kangaroo';


function replaceSomething(aString) {
 for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)  {
  mynewString = aString.replace(array[i].firstanimal, array[i].secondanimal);
 }
 return mynewString;
 }
```

Comment: Any input & output examples?

Comment: Your code is not enough understand the problem.. Add sample data

Comment: I´ve edited the example! @TheReason

Answer (score 0):

You would have to call replace on the replaced string `returnThis` in the second iteration and so on, or you just mutate the passed string:

```
function replaceDescription(aString) {
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
        aString = aString.replace(arrayOfObjects[i].item1, anyfunction(arrayOfObjects[i].item2).length).replace(arrayOfObjects[i].item3, anotherfunction(anyfunction(arrayOfObjects[i].item2)));
    }
    return aString;
}
```

Then you also get rid of that implicit global (bad!) variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, i have no idea what your object with the keyword/replacement looks like so i made my own.

```js
var text = 'This is my text that i want to replace keywords with values in';
var map = [ {keyword: 'text', replacement: 'butts'},
      {keyword: 'want', replacement: 'butts'}]
            
map.forEach(function(value, index){
 text = text.replace(new RegExp(value.keyword, 'g'), value.replacement);
});

console.log(text);
```